# Periodic batching

Tags: multithreading, go

I'm trying to just write logs out every N seconds or when the buffer gets too big, so that I don't send external log requests too large and that I limit data loss to at most N seconds. For the life of me, I cannot seem to find any sample code to do this. Most of the examples like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284349/periodically-flushing-channel-in-golang) either have a timer but don't have a max size, or have a max size but allow for complete data loss (no timer).

I know that I can use `timer.Tick` to "timeout" on filling the buffer, but:

- Do I just use a slice to implement the buffer? I feel like I'm re-inventing buffered channels then
- There shouldn't be any race condition, right? e.g. Between the `timer.Tick` event and the "buffer capacity reached"?

This is my code but it feels very wrong:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func populateChannel(outp chan int) {
    i := 0

    // emit an item every second
    // but 10th item, dump out 200 items fast
    timerChan := time.Tick(1 * time.Second)
    for _ = range timerChan {
        count := 1
        if i%10 == 0 {
            count = 200 + 1
        }
        for j := 1; j <= count; j++ {
            outp <- i
            i++
        }
    }
}

func processBatches(inp chan []int) {
    for batch := range inp {
        fmt.Printf("Got new batch of len=%d, cap=%d: %v\n", len(batch), cap(batch), batch)
    }
}

func main() {
    maxBatchSize := 100

    // I feel like this totally defeats the purpose of channels
    currentBatch := make([]int, 0, maxBatchSize)

    unbufChan := make(chan int)
    go populateChannel(unbufChan)

    timerChan := time.Tick(5 * time.Second)
    batchedChan := make(chan []int, 1)

    go processBatches(batchedChan)

    for {
        select {
        case item := <-unbufChan:
            currentBatch = append(currentBatch, item)
            fmt.Printf("Got item %v. Batch size = %d\n", item, len(currentBatch))
            if len(currentBatch) >= maxBatchSize {
                fmt.Println("Max batch size reached. New batch")
                // TODO: refactor
                batch := currentBatch // what if the timer case hits at this exact moment? Could it even?
                currentBatch = make([]int, 0, maxBatchSize)
                batchedChan <- batch
            }
        case <-timerChan:
            fmt.Println("Max time reached. Current batch too stale. New batch")
            // TODO: refactor
            batch := currentBatch
            currentBatch = make([]int, 0, maxBatchSize)
            batchedChan <- batch
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "This is my code but it feels very wrong:" Does it work as intended?

Comment: It works but I'm worried that I'm not using channels properly, and that I may have a race condition.

Comment: There is no race condition in your code. You can easily check this with the race-detector tool (see details [here](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector). To use it, just run `go build -race` or `go run -race main.go`

Answer (score 2):

> Do I just use a slice to implement the buffer? I feel like I'm re-inventing buffered channels then

A buffered channel is just a way to allow goroutines to be more independent when they are producing/consuming a channel.

> There shouldn't be any race condition, right? e.g. Between the timer.Tick event and the "buffer capacity reached"?

No, because the code you are talking about is not concurrent (the `select` statement will run only one of the two loop).

---

Is it expected, that even if some batches were sent in the meantime, a new batch will be send at 5 seconds? Shouldn't the timer be reset, when a batch is sent?

Anyway, I would recommend you to put this `ingester` in a struct, for instance like this:

```
type ingester struct {
    MaxSize  int
    MaxDelay time.Duration
}

func (ing ingester) Forward(in <-chan int, out chan<- []int) {
    defer close(out)
    buf := make([]int, 0, ing.MaxSize)

    deadline := time.After(ing.MaxDelay)

    sendBufferAndResetDeadline := func() {
        out <- buf
        buf = make([]int, 0, ing.MaxSize)
        deadline = time.After(ing.MaxDelay)
    }

    for {
        select {
        case i, ok := <-in:
            if !ok {
                if len(buf) > 0 {
                    sendBufferAndResetDeadline()
                }
                return
            }
            buf = append(buf, i)
            if len(buf) >= ing.MaxSize {
                sendBufferAndResetDeadline()
            }
        case <-deadline:
            sendBufferAndResetDeadline()
        }
    }
}
```

Your `main` would then look like this:

```
func main() {
    maxBatchSize := 100

    // I feel like this totally defeats the purpose of channels
    currentBatch := make([]int, 0, maxBatchSize)

    unbufChan := make(chan int)
    go populateChannel(unbufChan)

    batchedChan := make(chan []int, 1)

    go processBatches(batchedChan)

    ing := ingester{
        MaxSize:  maxBatchSize,
        MaxDelay: 5 * time.Second,
    }

    ing.Forward(unbufChan, batchedChan)
}
```